# Is $ord(a)=1$ equivalent to $a=e$?

Tags: group-theory

I write at my notebook:

$ord(a)=?? \Leftrightarrow a=e$

and I forgor to write the number after $ord(a)$, I guess that it was "1", I'm right?

Thank you!!

Comment: What is the definition of the order of an element of a group?

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it...:-)

Comment: Why I got -1?? 
It wan't a goor Q?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes. By definition of order you can "feel" that.